# How do I check whether Stage Manager is enabled?

Tags: macos, stage, macos-ventura

In macOS 13 Ventura

How do I check if Stage Manager is enabled in my code? And I want to turn the Stage Manager on or off with code.

Comment: I love detailed and clear documentation from Apple. Spoiler: No.